# How to get rid of scientifc notation in the y-axis of this .plot.bar() pandas figure?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I tried using `plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')`, but since the figure has been created using pandas, `df.plot.bar()`, it is not working. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
ax = df.plot.bar(x="Place", y="Amount", rot=30, title="Amount of ...", legend=False)
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y');
```

Of course, parameters passed to *df.plot.bar* are according to my source data.
Set them according to your environment.

Importans points are:

- save the result of *df.plot.bar* in a variable (*axes* object),
- set tick label format only for *y* axis.